# Laravel get product id from collection

Tags: php, sql, laravel, laravel-5.4, laravel-query-builder

I want to get all the products by passing array of `ids` which are from other table

i'm able to get all the `product_id` as in the `dd($main_categorie_ids);` but unable to pass it in other query and get the required data

```
    public function getHomeData($warehouse_id)
    {
        //get warehouse_table_name by warehouse_id
        $warehouse_table = Warehouse::where('id', $warehouse_id)
                                    ->select('table_name')
                                    ->first();

        //get all products from warehouse_table_name table
        $main_categorie_ids = DB::table($warehouse_table->table_name)
                                ->select('product_id')
                                ->get()
                                ->toArray();

        dd($main_categorie_ids);

        //dd result
        array:2 [
          0 => {#210
            +"product_id": 1
          }
          1 => {#209
            +"product_id": 2
          }
        ]

        //get distinct main_categories by id (line 29)
        $main_categorie = Product::whereIn('id', $main_categorie_ids['product_id'])
                                 ->groupBy('main_category_id')
                                 ->get();

        //get banners of main_categories by id 

        //get parent_categories by main_category_id 
    }
```

i am getting error

```
(1/1) ErrorException
Undefined index: product_id
in HomeController.php (line 29)
```

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `pluck` method to get only ids, like this:

```
$productIds = DB::table($warehouse_table->table_name)
                            ->select('product_id')
                            ->distinct()
                            ->pluck('product_id')
                            ->toArray();
$products = Product::whereIn('id', $productIds)->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

you are having more than 1 array in the collection so to use a specific one you need to pass the index
so try this

```
$main_categorie = Product::whereIn('id', $main_categorie_ids[0]->product_id)->get();
```

for the 1st one, if you want to access the 2nd one

```
$main_categorie = Product::whereIn('id', $main_categorie_ids[1]->product_id)->get();
```

Comment: thank you for your time, i did try that but i got different error `Cannot use object of type stdClass as array`